# Color style/scheme for IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, styles, color-scheme

Are there color style for IntelJ IDEA like this http://studiostyl.es/schemes/coding-horror-2010 ?
I've used this style in VS and can say it is very cool!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make your own scheme in Settings -> Appearance -> Colors & Fonts.

I'm attaching some Visual Studio-like schema in [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27012454/Visual_Studio_Enhanced.xml) - you can use it by placing it under `C:\Users\<UserName>\<Intellij Folder>\config\colors` and choosing it in settings.

Comment: I've done it, Thanks, and trying to load my colorcheme to the http://ideacolorschemes.com but plugin is not working :( waiting to hotfix and upload my scheme.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know this site!